# Achieve Infinite Scrolling for a platformer game using cocos2d language objective c

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, scroll

I am trying to develop an 2D game using cocos2d library.  I am still learning the framework.

Please understand that I am new to game development but not new to programming using objective c.

Here is the issue I am facing when it comes to my game development effort - I feel that I am missing the theoretical understanding of how to develop an infinite scrolling game. Is it possible for any of you to provide me some guidance on that ?

Here is my understanding of achieving infinite scrolling using cocos2d framework:

1. Cocos2d has a singleton director class which handles the current scene and scene transitions
2. In the current scene, I feel like I have to create an platform object consisting of several images and add them as a child to the current layer. And constantly run a move action to the platform sprite. So as and when I detect a particular image is off screen I have to replace it with another image. That way I will be able to create an infinite scrolling.

I am sorry if point 2 is not coherent. I just attempted to put my understanding of how to infinite scrolling.

Can you please help me with this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I dissected how to implement scrolling with cocos2d-iphone [in this article](http://www.koboldtouch.com/display/IDCAR/Four+Ways+of+Scrolling+with+Cocos2D). What you probably want is the "fake scrolling" approach where two background images are moved and switch position after one completely left the screen.

You want to do this for the background layer only, not individual sprites. Your world isn't really moving, it's just the background panning that creates the illusion of movement. All sprites etc (player, enemies) movement is still relative to screen coordinates.

You'll find a working implementation in the [code for my Learn Cocos2D 2 book](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/book-learn-cocos2d/) in the Shoot'em Up project.

If you don't want to bother implementing this yourself, [KoboldTouch supports endless/infinite scrolling](http://www.koboldtouch.com/x/cYBq) for tilemaps. Here the game objects actually move along with the background infinitely (up to the maximum coordinates supported by float which is around +/- 16 million points).

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I am unable to comprehend it fully. Can you please point out to platformer framework in iOS ? if they exist.